# Implementing FIDO2 Device Registration as WebAuthn for 2FA using Robot Framework and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, robotframework

I'm working on a project where I need to implement FIDO2 device registration as a WebAuthn method for 2FA within our application. We're using Robot Framework with Python for automation. I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve this. Here are the specific points I'd like assistance with:

Setting Up FIDO2 Device Registration:

How can I set up FIDO2 device registration using Python libraries?
Integration with WebAuthn:

How do I integrate the registered FIDO2 devices with WebAuthn in my web application?
Robot Framework Implementation:

Are there specific Robot Framework libraries or python libraries that can help automate FIDO2 device registration using WebAuthn?

I have install the python webauthn library but I'm not able to use it according to my application.